# Git Tower: How to show untracked files in Modified list?

Tags: git, git-tower

When I add new files to a directory being tracked by git, the files do not appear in the Modified view in Tower. I can add them by going to All view, navigating to the file, right clicking and then Add, but that's a pain. I'm surprised they don't show up automatically, and I'm wondering if there's a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is not a Git Tower issue, but controlled by a setting in the git repo.

In Terminal, navigate to the directory for the git repository and then enter

```
git config status.showuntrackedfiles normal (or all)
```

`status.showuntrackedfiles` was set to "no". The default is "normal". Clearly I'm using Tower to avoid the command line, and I've never heard of "git config status anything"; so how this came to be I have no idea. I sent a suggestion to the developer to add a checkbox to toggle showing untracked files in Modified view.